# Sticky menu flickering intermittently

Tags: html, css

The sticky menu on our site (http://462184.hs-sites.com/) is experiencing issues on some pages and not others.

For example the homepage, if you scroll half way down the page and try to use the menu, it hides momentarily. On the other hand we don't get this issue when on another page such as (http://462184.hs-sites.com/bookkeeping-plans).

Therefore I can only imagine it is some type of element on those pages conflicting?

I've already modified the `overflow: hidden`, to be set to `overflow: auto`, and this works quite well in the `.header-container`, although it seems that although this fixes the problem, there is still the issue when this is set that the images (such as the iPad at the top of the page, then overlaps the next section below it).

Thoughts on how to make sure either the image extends the container so it doesn't run into the next one, or how to fix this once and for all?

**Just a thought, could this possibly be the Javascript, as I noticed that the menu bar when scrolled down doesn't dissapear until hovering over an active/Javascript link in the nav bar.**

Your support is greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

If you put a console.log in your call:

```
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > 500 && getScreenWidth > 767) console.log("true")  
        else console.log("false")
```

Do you see in your console log the value changing when you scroll down at your homepage? And is this the same output as on your bookkeeping-plans page?

and does it also appear if you remove the slideup and slidetoggle functions?

```
    $(this).parent().siblings('.hs-item-has-children').find('.hs-menu-children-wrapper').slideUp(250);
    $(this).next('.hs-menu-children-wrapper').slideToggle(250);
```

This is what I can think of that is conflicting your code based on what I see on your website